# Applying class methods to a whole ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am wondering if there is a bit of code or that can apply a method from a class to all of the objects in the `ArrayList`? I'm making a basic space invaders program and I am trying to implement a move method that will apply to all of enemies, so that they move in a group rather than individually.

I've created the items in the array list here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    venWidth = venWidth - 139;
    enemyList.add(new Venusian("/venusian.jpg", venWidth, height));
        }

for (int i = 6; i < 12; i++) {
    merWidth = merWidth - 145;
    enemyList.add(new Mercurian("/mercurian.jpg", merWidth, merHeight));
        }


for (int i = 12; i < 18; i++) {
    marWidth = marWidth - 125;
    enemyList.add(new Martian("/martian.jpg", marWidth, marHeight));
    }
```

Here is where I call the move method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemyList.size(); i++) {
        Invader Invaders = (Invader) enemyList.get(i);
        Invaders.draw(g);
        Invaders.Move(1024);
```

This makes them move independently and overlap, at the moment I am just moving them right and left using the boundaries of my created window. So is there any way of moving them together at the same time? I have searched for a way to apply a class method to all of the lists items but I haven't found anything after a couple of hours.

Any material, sources or advice relating to this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just do two passes: one for the drawing, and another for moving. Then the display should be in consistent state.

Comment: And additional: the list operator you are looking for has the name foreach. You  can call it via list.foreach. There are other interesting list operators which may interest you. Map, fold, filter for example. But the names for them are different in java.

Comment: And you are doing strange things with the widths. Maybe the naming of the vars is wrong there?

Comment: I am just using the image sizes and the parent width of the window to draw them, I plan on going back later after I get the functionally done and touching it up a bit as the images are quite bad.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to come up with a solution that can decouple the Invaders you are moving from those you are displaying. 
This is due to the fact that your individual Invaders will always be more or less sequentially moved - even if you are working with multiple threads, etc. Even if you would start using Java8 Lambdas to write your code like this:

```
ArrayList<Invader> badGuys;
//fill your List here
badGuys.forEach( badGuy -> badGuy.move());
```

This would also create intermediate states where some Invaders were moved, some were not.

So you have to make sure that you only draw a consistent set of Invaders to your screen. You could do this several ways:

- Only draw to screen after all Invaders were moved
- Make a copy of your invaders for drawing, while the Invaders are being moved. After all Invaders were moved, start displaying the Invaders from the moved List
  ...

1st Edit: How do you draw the Invaders to screen? Is this happening in separate threads?

3rd EDIT: Okay so maybe you can stop your timerThread before starting to move your Invaders. And when you are finished with moving them you can restart the timer again. Check what methods your timer offers It should have start() and stop() or maybe suspend() methods.

Do something like this:

```
 timer.stop();
 badGuys.moveAll();
 timer.start();
```

2nd EDIT: Just looked over your code again. There is no need for you to start your for loop number 2 and 3 from indexes other than 0. Your code will be easier to read if for example you just say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { // start from 0 (to 6) instead of 6 to 12
    merWidth = merWidth - 145;
    enemyList.add(new Mercurian("/mercurian.jpg", merWidth, merHeight));
}
```

Comment: I am using a timer to redraw the screen redrawTimer = new Timer(10, this); and to redraw the screen public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
  this.repaint();
 } I am not quite sure what you mean by thread

Comment: Well this means that your redrawing takes place in a separate thread from your code moving your invaders. These two parts of your program execute in parallel. You have to take care of the synchronisation or otherwise you will end up painting half moved and overlapping Invader Icons to your screen.

Comment: Ah thanks, thought i had to specify the exact index.

Answer (score -1):

create an interface like Moveable. and put Move method on it. then implement it on Venusian, Martian and Mercurian. and use this interface on arraylist

```
interface Moveable {
public void Move(int dist);
}

class Mercurian implements Moveable {
public void Move(int dist)
{
  //do something
}
}
class Venusian implements Moveable {
public void Move(int dist)
{
  //do something
}
}

class Martian implements Moveable {
public void Move(int dist)
{
  //do something
}
}

ArrayList<Moveable> enemyList = new ArrayList<Moveable>();
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with what Iain is asking has it?

Comment: I have a EnemyBase class that has a Move(); method, if I implement the interface and leave it blank will the method be called from the parent class to each of the enemy classes, or will I have to implement duplicate move methods in each class for the interface to work?

Comment: The interface has nothing to do with your problem. Since you have a common base class you can already specify a proper type for your ArrayList. The interface does not provide an implementation of the methods it just specifies their signatures. But if all your implementations inherit from your EnemyBase class they would also inherit its move method and would therefore match the interface definition. It would however be easier if you wanted to have the Interface to specify that your base class EnemyBase implements the Interface.

Comment: as I understand, you have not a game thread. I suggest to you create a thread, put a infinite loop and do all movements in it. create two method. one of it is current Move, and is called when you press or touch something. switch a boolean in this function. don't change coordinate in it. and create a second function, like moveOnTick. this second is called always in game thread and checks boolean switch to make a step. for this kind of stuff there are many physic libs. but of course you can do it with yourself too. check this tutorial, http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game2.html

Comment: Thanks markus and Adem, will read the tutorial and try that with my main enemy class